# Finding blind_SQL vulnerability in php site code

Tags: php, sql, security

Hi I'm really a beginner in the web domain and I was wondering if someone could guide me in where should I look for the blind sql injection vulnerability in the code of the whole forum
For example if this is the exploit of the vulnerability `index.php?m=content&c=rss&catid=[valid catid]`
where should I look for in the code for the portion which validates user form & url input; I'm really a beginner in php and how should I fix it.

Comment: ah, beginner in the web domain (mind the pun)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about SQL Injection then you have bad design.  You should be using parametrized queries with a library like ADODB or PDO. Then there is no question,  you are 100% protected against SQL Injection.

For testing for blind sql you can do somthing like:
`index.php?m=content&c=rss&catid=sleep(30)`.

This request should take 30 seconds for the page to load. If you need a quote mark then the payload would look something like `' and sleep(30) or 1='`.

To patch this vulnerability you know that catid should be an int.  So at the top of that page you can add this line:
`$_GET['catid']=intval($_GET['catid']);`

Comment: The statement "...you are 100% protected..." gives a false sense of security. A naïve programmer could get it into their head to store SQL snippets in a table for future evaluation, thinking that parameterised queries make it perfectly safe to store such snippets without risk of an injection attack.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos  wow yeah i guess.  If the programmer fails that badly then he deserves to be HACKED TO TEARS.

Comment: Every programmer starts out naïve. I would actually be quite impressed by a novice programmer who had the creativity to store SQL snippets for some kind of extensibility mechanism — kind of like inventing higher-order programming for databases. So I would compliment them on the insight and initiative they've shown, then I would gently explain to them why it's usually a bad idea. I certainly wouldn't berate them and say, "Dude, you deserve to be PWND!" That wouldn't be helpful in the least.

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of material around where to read about php security. A few links:

- http://php.robm.me.uk/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious
- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/secure-your-web-applications-by-validating-user-input-with-php/6078577

Your question regarding form input: One of the first things you should look into and use is [mysql_real_escape_string](http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Comment: And where exactly (what file of php) should I look for it; if the problem lies in unfiltering of table id's

Comment: Sorry, I don't know phpcms, and can't help you with that in detail. But there should be an index.php, in there (or another fork) somewhere catid and content is filtered. If phpcms does this any good, they should've taken care on the things I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But how would mysql_real_escape_string control valid id scope; isn't its only purpose to escape invalid strings; if I type id 177 and get error, would I just replace it with the valid error page so to mask dbo respone or something else, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. If you actually want the user to go to id 177 and it, for example, ain't in the database and therefore you receive an ugly error, then the problem is not security, but more like improper error handling.

Comment: I don't want possibility of true-false blind sql injection over unchecked id's

Comment: I got that, and mysql_real_escape_string() helps alot against this by properly escaping the user input. But where exactly this is in place in your application I can only guess.

Comment: If your question is, where do you check if the CMS of your choice takes care of this, it might be better to ask the community of your CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Each $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, (and even $_SERVER) superglobal input must be validated and not trusted.

If you use any of them in your code, if it's going to database, use mysql_real_escape_string; if it will be displayed directly as html on your website (as well as if it is called from the database), you should check for XSS, using functions like htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, strip_tags etc.

Comment: Don't forget about $_SERVER.  Many of its variables can be controlled by an attacker.  such as referer.  Also parametrized quires will always solve this problem regardless of where the attack is coming from.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't mention it, because $_SERVER is not used that often, especially for plugging in directly to the site and I never see it used to be stored in the database, though some developers do do that dangerously. So it's good you mention it.

Comment: In what files can I find those critical user insert controls for URL                            http://download.phpcms.cn/phpsso/phpsso_UTF8.zip